# In MS-Word how do you VBA split a table inserting a Section Break AND a paragraph mark

Tags: vba, ms-word

wdSectionBreakNextPage does not come with a trailing paragraph mark

I have a massive table i copy from excel to word sprinkled throughout with homemade fields PAGEX and SECTIONX. My macro will change these to page and section breaks, splitting the table for each (what I want). But page breaks come with a trailing paragraph mark before the table and section breaks do not. My feeble attempts to insert a paragraph mark after a section break always ends up with the paragraph mark inside the table.

My goal is to get the same gap between my header and the beginning of the table after both section breaks and page breaks. I think I simply want a macro to insert a paragraph mark after my section breaks similar to the way wdPageBreak works (i.e., between the break and the table). But I'm open to suggestions.

As perhaps further clarification, doing this manually involves creating a new row after a section break, then converting that row to text (quite impractical for the counts I'm looking at).

```
    Do While .Execute
        Selection.Delete
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Loop
```

Comment: Add Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd, Selection.insertParagraph after the .InsertBreak?

Comment: Thanks for the response Freeflow but your solution merely added a paragraph mark inside the table. I need the paragraph mark between the section break and the table.

Comment: Ok.  Misread the word help on insertbreak.  If you want the gap between the table and the inserted section break do Selection.Moveleft unit:=wdcharacter,: Selection.InsertBreak

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ActiveDocument.Compatibility(wdSplitPgBreakAndParaMark) = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's unclear what I would do with it. wdSplitPgBreakAndParaMark is not part of my VBA drop-down selection menu (and it throws out an error when run).

Comment: That code line changes a document compatibility setting. The Word VBE should reveal wdSplitPgBreakAndParaMark as an option when you type ActiveDocument.Compatibility(. Of course, since you haven't told us anything about which office version you're using, whether you're running your code from Word and, if not, whether you're using early or late binding, you haven't really given enough information to work with...

Answer (score 0):

thanks free and macro. i probably should have noted that i'm a vba novice (cut-and-paste mostly).
i decided it was easiest to just insert a page break after each section break, and then do a replace of ^m^p by ^p.

this works in my case, but won't work for others reading this if they have existing page breaks they don't want to lose.

GJ